# How can I transfer files in a folder into consecutive pre-made worksheets in my workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder, which I need to bring in 29 files into 29 worksheets in a template wb. there are 31 total worksheets, but I need to start placing them after sheet 2.

I first place the relevant sheet names into an array:

```
Dim wbTemplate As Workbook: Set wbTemplate = ThisWorkbook
Dim wsInputs As Worksheet: Set wsInputs = wbTemplate.Worksheets("Inputs")
Dim strDate As String: strDate = InputBox("Please Enter Date of Data (mm/dd/yyyy) : ", Default:=Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy"))
Dim strFolderName As String: strFolderName = InputBox("Please Enter Data Folder Date (mm.dd.yy) Include 0's: ", Default:=Format(Now, "mm.dd.yy"))

'place wbTemplate sheet names into an array
With wbTemplate
    Dim varWsName, i
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    ReDim varWsName(1 To Sheets.Count)
            For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
            Select Case ws.Name
                Case "Inputs", "Data --->>>"
                Case Else
                ws(i) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
            End Select
            Next
        .wsInputs.Range("B1").Value = strDate
        .wsInputs.Range("B2").Value = strFolderName
End With
```

getting an `object variable or with block not set` on this line: 
                Select Case ws.Name

and then I want to know if this line will properly start placing the first file in the folder in sheet 1 after the case statement, and then second file will place in sheet 2 and so forth:

```
        With wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            .UsedRange.Copy Destination:=wbTemplate.Worksheets(varWsName(i))
        End With
```

Rest of code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Update_Data_And_OPR()
    Dim wbTemplate As Workbook: Set wbTemplate = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wsInputs As Worksheet: Set wsInputs = wbTemplate.Worksheets("Inputs")
    Dim strDate As String: strDate = InputBox("Please Enter Date of Data (mm/dd/yyyy) : ", Default:=Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy"))
    Dim strFolderName As String: strFolderName = InputBox("Please Enter Data Folder Date (mm.dd.yy) Include 0's: ", Default:=Format(Now, "mm.dd.yy"))

    'place wbTemplate sheet names into an array
    With wbTemplate
        Dim varWsName, i
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        ReDim varWsName(1 To Sheets.Count)
                For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
                Select Case ws.Name
                    Case "Inputs", "Data --->>>"
                    Case Else
                    ws(i) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
                End Select
                Next
            .wsInputs.Range("B1").Value = strDate
            .wsInputs.Range("B2").Value = strFolderName
    End With

    'compile all files in folder into wbTemplate
    Dim filePath As String: filePath = strFolderName & "*.xlsx"
    Dim fileName As String: fileName = Dir(filePath)
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim k As Long
        Do While fileName <> ""
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strFolderName & fileName)

            With wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
                .UsedRange.Copy Destination:=wbTemplate.Worksheets(varWsName(i))
            End With
            wb.Close
        fileName = Dir
        Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: You're getting that error because you never `Set ws`: `Select Case ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name` if you're looping with `i`, or change your loop to loop through all worksheets.

Comment: @BigBen, funny you mention that because I just figured that out as I saw your comment. So, when I go to start printing each files data into its corresponding worksheet, how would I make sure `varWsName(1)` and `varWsName(2)` get deleted when I start  moving the files into the template? I want `varWsName(1)` index spot to be the first worksheet that's picked up after the case statement. it now shows two empty spots in my array because of the case statement to skip 2 worksheets

Comment: Don't use `i` then as the index in the array.

Comment: How else would I specify the third index in `varWsName`?

Comment: @BigBen like: `wbTemplate.Worksheets(varWsName(i + 2))`?

Comment: No... don't use `i` at all. Use a separate counter for the array.

Comment: @BigBen, sorry, I guess I don't follow in terms of incorporating another counter.. this is my first time with something like this

Comment: Don't loop through all the worksheets - just loop from `3 to Worksheets.Count`.

Comment: Ok, I got that piece working, as for the `.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(varWsName(i))` part, its resulting in a `copy method of range class failed` error

Comment: You're missing a range on the destination sheet.

Comment: @Ok, I got that to print, but its printing at the last index for varWsName. Is there a reason why it doesn't reference the first index in the array? How can I make sure it knows to start printing to the first worksheet name in the array?

Comment: You might just start a new question here...